# How to use font-face font family in react component render?

Tags: reactjs

index.css

```
  @font-face{
    font-family:"Bauhaus";
    src:local('BAUHS'),
      url('./BAUHS.ttf') format('truetype');
  }
```

I want to use the  "Bauhaus" font in my react component index.js file based on certain condition. Could you please help how to use it.

Here is my code:

```
 import './index.css';
 class NameForm extends React.Component {
   constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.state = {fontFamilyName: ''};

      this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
   }
    handleChange(event) { 
     this.setState({fontFamilyName: event.target.value});
    } 
    render() { 
      return ( 
            <div> 
                <select onChange={this.handleChange}>
                   <option value='Arial'>Arial</option>
                   <option value='Bauhaus'>Bauhaus</option>
                   <option value='Times New Roman'>Times New Roman</option> 
                </select> 
                <p style={{fontFamily:this.state.fontFamilyName}}>Some Text here</p>
            </div> ); 
     }
   }
```

Comment: what's the issue? share how you are using it?

Comment: I have used font family like  <p style={{fontFamily:this.state.fontFamilyName}}></p> in my component. Here this.state.fontFamilyName is dymanically getting based on condition.

Comment: can you please share that code

Comment: I have shared my code.

Comment: You are expecting the value from your traget but, see it's undefined. Try to pass value attribute in `option` like  `value='Arial'` .

Comment: I have value attribute also ,but it is not working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remember that "truetype" works for Safari, Android and iOS (https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/using-font-face/).

Declare a font-face this way (just an example in one of my projects):

```
@font-face {
font-family: '3dumbregular';
src: url('fonts/3Dumb-webfont.eot');
src: url('fonts/3Dumb-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
     url('fonts/3Dumb-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
     url('fonts/3Dumb-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
     url('fonts/3Dumb-webfont.svg#3dumbregular') format('svg');
}
```

Multiple formats for multiple browsers support.

In your example you miss even the "select" value. Add value to select:

```
<select onChange={this.handleChange} value = {this.state.fontFamilyName}>
           <option value='Arial'>Arial</option>
           <option value='Bauhaus'>Bauhaus</option>
           <option value='Times New Roman'>Times New Roman</option> 
 </select>
```

Comment: Thank You for response. I tried this but font family is not applying.

Comment: @user3278227 could you please create a jsFiddle (or something similar) with your code?

Comment: hi, I have added my code here - https://jsfiddle.net/n5u2wwjg/56014/        , I am checking Jenkins font family online links to run this exapmle.

Comment: The change from Arial to Times New Roman works. The option for Jenkins should have as value 'Jenkins 2.0' because it is the font family name. You have still '3dumbregular' in SVG and there is not fonts folder

Comment: This is a jsfiddle with your code. I have taken a font from Tumblr. In your code use the font you prefer (possibily in your font folder): https://jsfiddle.net/stxdovh5/